# Root partition size differences among different tools

Tags: filesystem, disk, disk-usage, disk-management

I just finished running 'Disk Usage Analyzer' on my **root partition, /dev/sda3** with a total of **122.5G**.

The Analyzer reports that only **26.8GB** of space has been used but my root partition is showing **68.7GB** available instead of **95.7GB.**

I have ran `fsck`, but  nothing changes.
I also read somewhere about shadow copies but I am not sure.

On running the: `df -h` command on terminal, I get:

```
/dev/sda3 --> Total: 115G   Used: 51G   Available: 59G  Use %: 47%
```

On using **Disk Utility**:

File system Partition: **125GB** ext4, Free: **69GB** | 45% full

On **Nautilus**, it shows a Total: **122.5GB**, **53.7GB** used, **62.5GB** free

Also, every time I boot, it checks for file system errors and cleans it.

Please, can someone explain the cause of this discrepancy and how to correct it.

Answer (score 0):

I just resolved this problem by deleting some backup rescued files in the .Trash-0 hidden folder on the root partition.

Now it reads on Disk Usage Analyzer **95.9 GB** Available with a Total of **122.5GB**

26.6GB used, 89.6GB free on nautilus

and on running the: df -h command on terminal, I get:

/dev/sda3 --> Total: 115G   Used: 25G   Available: 84G  Use %: 23%